# How to get the text for radio buttons using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form action=""><input type="radio" id="r1" name="city" value="la">Los Angeles</br><input type="radio" id="r2" name="city" value="sf">San Francisco</br>input type="radio" id="r3" name="city" value="ny">New York</br><input type="radio" id="r4" name="city" value="chicago">Chicago</br></form>
```

In Selenium WebDriver using Java, I am trying to capture the text of each radio button (so "Los Angeles", "San Francisco", etc.) Here is my code:

```
public static void radioTest(WebDriver driver){
List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("city"));
for(int i = 0; i<radios.size(); i++){
    radios.get(i).click(); 
    System.out.println(radios.get(i).getAttribute("value"));

}
```

}

The problem here is that it is returning "la", "sf", etc., when I want the actual text ("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", etc.) Can anyone please offer any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check by getText() method instead of value attribute and check

```
for(int i = 0; i<radios.size(); i++){
    radios.get(i).click(); 
    System.out.println(radios.get(i).getText());

}
```

Comment: Let me know if you get any issue with the above code.

Comment: Hello, I've tried using your code. I'm getting blank lines (as in, it's not printing anything other than white spaces)

Comment: comment this line radios.get(i).click();  and check once. Also have debug and checked what does radios return in your case?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It says:

Comment: City name is : (blank, goes like this for 4 times)

Answer (score 0):

You can install a developer tools on chrome or safari to check the properties and their run time values. In chrome you can open developer tools, go to 'Elements' tab, click on the element of interest. It will show the properties of element in the right side. There yo can see which property/attribute you are interested in and get the value accordingly using code.

Answer (score 0):

it returns "la", "sf", etc. beacuse you are extracting `value` attribute using `getAttribute()` method, for the text you have to use `getText()` method.

Try this code and let me konw any issue occured:

```
public static void radioTest(WebDriver driver){
List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.name("city"));
for(int i = 0; i<radios.size(); i++){
    radios.get(i).click(); 
    String cityName=radios.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println("Name of city: "+cityName);
}

}
```

Comment: It is printing "Name of city: " four times. The cityName variable is showing up as whitespace.

Comment: Strange let me check once

Comment: You can practice on my actual website:

Answer (score 0):

To capture the text of each radio button, you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> my_cities = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='city' and @type='radio']"));
for (WebElement city:my_cities)
    System.out.println("City name is : " + city.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: I am getting "City name is : " four times (showing white space for where city.getAttribute("innerHTML")) is supposed to be)

Comment: Can you format the `HTML` with in your Question just like the actual `HTML`?

Comment: Here's the actual page (you can just right-click inspect): http://kanglincheng.com/selenium2.html